# Bash: move file/directory and create a link of it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, move, symlink

I am trying to make a bash script that moves a file or directory from source directory to destination directory and puts a symlink to it into source directory.

So, `<source_path>` can be a file or directory, `<destination_dir_path>` is the directory where I want the original moved to.

Sample usage:

```
$ mvln /source_dir/file.txt /destination_dir/
OR
$ mvln /source_dir/dir_I_want_to_move/ /destination_dir/
```

This is what I have managed to put together, but it does not work properly.
It works only if source is a directory, otherwise mv returns an error:

```
mv: unable to rename `/source_dir/some_file.txt': Not a directory
```

And the directory is not moved into destination_directory but only its contents are moved.

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_NAME='mvln'
USAGE_STRING='usage: '$SCRIPT_NAME' <source_path> <destination_dir_path>'

# Show usage and exit with status
show_usage_and_exit () {
    echo $USAGE_STRING
    exit 1
}

# ERROR file does not exist
no_file () {
    echo $SCRIPT_NAME': '$1': No such file or directory'
    exit 2
}

# Check syntax
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    show_usage_and_exit
fi

# Check file existence
if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
    no_file $1
fi

# Get paths
source_path=$1
destination_path=$2

# Check that destination ends with a slash
[[ $destination_path != */ ]] && destination_path="$destination_path"/

# Move source
mv "$source_path" "$destination_path"

# Get original path
original_path=$destination_path$(basename $source_path)

# Create symlink in source dir
ln -s "$original_path" "${source_path%/}"
```

Can some one please help?

Comment: Define "does not work properly".

Comment: so far what I've tested your script seems to be working fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$destination_path` refers to a directory that doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
mv /path/to/file.txt /path/to/non/existent/directory/
```

returns an error, and

```
mv /path/to/directory/ /path/to/non/existent/directory/
```

will rename `/path/to/directory/` to `/path/to/non/existent/directory/` (provided that `/path/to/non/existent/` is an existent directory, just without a subfolder named `directory`).

If you are expecting that `$destination_path` doesn't already exist, then you can add a `mkdir` command:

```
mkdir "$destination_path"
mv "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

if you're expecting that it *might* not exist, then you can add it conditionally:

```
[[ -d "$destination_path" ]] || mkdir "$destination_path"
mv "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

and if you're expecting that it *does* exist, then you have some debugging to do!

(By the way, depending on your exact situation, you might find `mkdir -p` to be helpful. It recursively creates a directory *and* all necessary parent directories, and it doesn't mind if the directory already exists.)

Comment: ah i also had the directory created! nice catch